# Where save help information in outlook?

Tags: outlook-addin

I am making an add-in for outlook.
I periodically  get updated information from WCF-service and I need somewhere to save the last time the add-in was updated.
Where can I save this information?

Answer (score 0):

In a appSetting in the app.config file, sounds like a good place:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="UpdateDate" value="2013-08-27 10:00:00" />
</appSettings>
```

Comment: Can I save there login and password for my add-in if encrypt their?